# Suppression State Error CS1936 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'. 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been banging my head off the wall for the last couple hours in regard to this error, and please before marking this as a "duplicate" please read through the issue, I know as well as everyone else that this "could" be labeled a duplicate, I even came across my own question for this that was asked ages ago and the solution at that time was to delete my EDMX and regenerate it ;)

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'.  'Select' not found

I wrote a stored procedure in SSMS:

```
create procedure usp_GetMaterialByVendorID
    (@VendorID int)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

    DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY int,
            @MESSAGE varchar(1000),
            @ERROR_NUMBER int,
            @ERROR_PROCEDURE nvarchar(200),
            @ERROR_LINE int,
            @ERROR_MESSAGE nvarchar(4000);
    begin try
        select
            mat.MaterialID,
            mcat.MaterialCategoryID,
            mcat.MaterialCategory,
            mtype.MaterialType,
            mstype.MaterialSubType,
            mat.Description,
            mcost.Cost,
            mat.NewPrice,
            mat.RemodelPrice
        from 
            [Material] mat
        inner join 
            [MaterialCategory] mcat on mcat.MaterialCategoryID = mat.MaterialCategoryID
        inner join 
            [MaterialType] mtype on mtype.MaterialTypeID = mat.MaterialTypeID
        inner join 
            [MaterialSubType] mstype on mstype.MaterialSubTypeID = mat.MaterialSubTypeID
        inner join 
            [MaterialCost] mcost on mcost.MaterialID = mat.MaterialID
        where 
            mat.VendorID = @VendorID
    end try
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ISNULL(ERROR_SEVERITY(),'');
        SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ISNULL(ERROR_NUMBER(),'');
        SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''); 
        SET @ERROR_LINE = ISNULL(ERROR_LINE(),'');
        SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'');

        -- Test if the transaction is uncommittable.
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. Rolling back transaction.'
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END;

        -- Test if the transaction is active and valid.
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1
        BEGIN
            --PRINT N'The transaction is committable. Committing transaction.'
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;   
        END;

        SET @MESSAGE = 'Error occurred in stored procedure ' + cast(@ERROR_PROCEDURE as varchar(200)) + 
                    '; Line Number ' + cast(@ERROR_LINE as varchar) + 
                    '; Message: [' + cast(@ERROR_NUMBER as varchar) + '] - '
                    + cast(@ERROR_MESSAGE as varchar(255))

        RAISERROR(@MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1);
    END CATCH;
```

and then opened up the Entity Framework `.EDMX` file and updated from database and added the stored procedure. No problem.

Then I went into my DAL and wrote this here method

```
public List<VendorMaterials> GetMaterialsByVendorID(int id)
{
        UsherEntities = new ExovationsUsherEntities();

        List<VendorMaterials> lst = new List<VendorMaterials>();

        var query = from a in UsherEntities.usp_GetMaterialByVendorID(id)
                    select a;
        return lst;
}
```

Just like I have done many times in the project that I am working on.
and on this line

```
var query = from a in UsherEntities.usp_GetMaterialByVendorID(id)
            select a;
```

is where the error is thrown, so I did an F12 on the `usp_GetMaterialByVendorID` and found it and took a look at it and it looks like the other ones that I have

```
public virtual int usp_GetMaterialByVendorID(Nullable<int> vendorID)
{
        var vendorIDParameter = vendorID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("VendorID", vendorID) :
            new ObjectParameter("VendorID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("usp_GetMaterialByVendorID", vendorIDParameter);
}
```

Things I have tried are:

1. Opening up the Model Browser of the `.EDMX` file and deleted the stored procedure from the model and the store and reupdated the model. Didn't work.
2. Opening up the Model Browser of the `.EDMX` file and deleted the stored procedure from the model and the store and then deleted the stored procedure definition and reupdated the model. Didn't work.
3. Deleted and recreated the `.EDMX` all over again. Nope, didn't work either (and this had worked before for me)

I also did some researching and have run across this type of question before but didn't get any correct answers for my predicament or any solid reasoning why this happens or how to fix it. If worse comes to worse then I could write this out in LINQ but don't want to have to go that route.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This method which is nearly identical to one in question works

```
public List<VendorContact> GetVendorContactsByVendorID(int id)
    {
        UsherEntities = new ExovationsUsherEntities();

        List<VendorContact> lst = new List<VendorContact>();

        var query = from a in UsherEntities.usp_GetVendorContactByID(id)
                    select a;

        foreach(var a in query)
        {
            lst.Add(new VendorContact
            {
                VendorID = a.VendorID,
                ContactID = a.ContactID,
                ContactName = a.ContactName,
                FirstName = a.FirstName,
                LastName = a.LastName,
                Phone = a.Phone,
                Cell = a.Cell,
                Fax = a.Fax,
                Email = a.Email
            });
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

Comment: As the compiler is trying to tell you, it makes no sense to run a LINQ query on an `int`.  Just call that function.

Comment: Did you select `Complex` as return type when importing the SP?

Comment: @SLaks, I have written the same type of method over 30 times in my DAL. So can you elaborate a little more on your comment? This stored procedure returns multiple records based on the id being passed to it

Comment: I just made an edit and added a nearly identical method that uses the same thing and works

Comment: @IvanStoev, all I did was opened the EDMX file and right clicked in it and select Update Model from Database and added the new founded stored procedure

Comment: @Chris: No; the stored procedure returns an `int`.  Read the code / error message.  Sounds like you misconfigured your model.

Comment: Also, there is no point in ever writing `from x in y select x`.

Comment: @SLaks, I just ran the select statement in SSMS and its returning no rows because there are no records for it to call, which has no bearing on Entity Framework. So I am curious on where you came up with it returning an int because I am not seeing where it is possible

Comment: @SLaks, why is there no point in ever writing from x in y select x?

Comment: @Chris: Why would there be a point in writing that? What do you think it does?

Comment: `public virtual int usp_GetMaterialByVendorID(...)` Why do you think that doesn't return `int`?

Comment: @SLaks, ahhhh ok, i see now why you say its returning an int, i compared it again with one that is working and the others are returning an object and this one is not. Now I wonder how that got messed up, is it in the storedproc or did something go awry when i updated the model or even regenerated it for that matter

Comment: @SLaks, my understanding is that in your from x in y select x is, from this object select x and x is just a "holder"

Comment: But what do you think that whole expression _does_? What's the point? Why do you think it's different from just writing `y`?

Comment: That's a good question, I never really gave it much thought, I have always known to do things that way, when starting off learning about LINQ its always that way in the examples shown. I guess i could say I'm ignorant because I've always done it that way and learned it that way.My preference is to use ADO.Net over EF, but didn't have option to use ADO